# javascript stopped working after adding another element to html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new in web development, so just cannot get a logic. Please help me.
I have this index.html file.

```js
function unhide() {
  var x = document.getElementById("hiden").innerHTML;
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function changemenu(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
  unhide();
}
```

```css
body {
  min-width: 700px;
}

.TopLine {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}

#withak {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Blackadder ITC;
  padding-left: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  top: 15px;
  left: 95%;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  /*border:1px solid red;*/
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  /*border:2px solid red;*/
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}

.topnav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 70%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.topnav a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-family: Blackadder ITC;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:active {
  color: pink;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="TopLine">
  <a id="withak" href="index.html">WitHak</a>
  <div class="container" onclick="changemenu(this)">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="topnav" id="hiden">
    <a class="active" href="index.html">About Me</a>
    <a href="myWork.html">My Work</a>
    <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>About Me</h1>
  <img src="img/welcome.jpg" alt="Welcome">
  <p>Hello, happy to see you here, dear guest!</p>
</div>
```

After adding div with class "content" JavaScript stopped working.
 Why? What I did wrong? So if cut out this:

```
<div class="content">
        <h1>About Me</h1>
        <img src="img/welcome.jpg" alt="Welcome">
        <p>Hello, happy to see you here, dear guest!</p>
    </div>
```

Without this extra div everything was working ideally. I want to add many other elements and don't lose beauty of scripting.
What script is doing. Three menu lines after clicking on them transforms to X and unhides top menu. Clicking on X will hide menu again.

Comment: can you include a working code snippet? I think in here you are missing the css file, also can you explain what was working and what are you attempting to achieve

Comment: your current code is still not working so first paste here your working code.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Try closing the `<img>` tag and see if it fixes your problem; like so: `<img src="img/welcome.jpg" alt="Welcome" />`. Notice the `/>`.

Comment: @MariusBughiu `<img>` is a [void element](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/syntax.html#void-element). Doesn't need closing in HTML.

Comment: How to edit my question to add more details?

Comment: morilynx add css also

Comment: There are edit link option next line to your question tags javascript/html

Comment: You get `innerHTML` instead of the dom node `var x = document.getElementById("hiden").innerHTML;`. `innerHTML` has no `style` property.

Comment: Can you provide code example how to fix my problem?

Comment: yes sure I shall

Comment: @Morilynx please review an answer I have posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are 2 mistakes in your codes**

> 1. in css you do not set float:left to .content class.
> 2. in unhide() function you hide html text content with var x = document.getElementById("hiden").innerHTML to store in x variable and that is a reason it shows an error of undefined x.display.style.
>
> You should write var x = document.getElementById("hiden");

Please review working snippet.

```js
// Code goes here

function unhide() {
  var x = document.getElementById("hiden");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function changemenu(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
  unhide();
}
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

body {
  min-width: 700px;
}

.TopLine {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}

#withak {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Blackadder ITC;
  padding-left: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  top: 15px;
  left: 95%;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  /*border:1px solid red;*/
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  /*border:2px solid red;*/
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}

.topnav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 70%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.topnav a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-family: Blackadder ITC;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:active {
  color: pink;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="TopLine">
  <a id="withak" href="index.html">WitHak</a>
  <div class="container" onclick="changemenu(this)">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="topnav" id="hiden">
    <a class="active" href="index.html">About Me</a>
    <a href="myWork.html">My Work</a>
    <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>About Me</h1>
  <img src="img/welcome.jpg" alt="Welcome">
  <p>Hello, happy to see you here, dear guest!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just how float stopped script from working, I don't understand. Magic? And when to use innerHTML and when not, what it is doing?

Comment: By the way it helped, so big thanks to you. Will try to get logic.

Comment: innerHTML is a function which may retrieve HTML content so whenever you required storing element reference just use var xyz = document.getElementById("idenOfElement"); like that way and later on you may use xyz.innerHTML like method you should use.

Comment: still let me what is the issue to access an answer I shall try to help you.

Comment: How did you noticed that I miss float:left, because not only innerHTML was the reason of my problem. Where is the logic? How do you know that I need float: left?

Comment: because if I put simple HTML with no content without CSS it's working so I replace it with your content without CSS, it 's working so definitely there is an issue with CSS. That is the way I find it.